# Monthly Dummy Variables in ARIMA model

Tags: r, dummy-variable, arima

I'm trying to run an ARIMA model with monthly dummy variables using the xreg option. Ultimately, what I am trying to do is specify multiple dummy variables in xreg. 
I've tried these ways:

```
fit100_month = Arima(series, order=c(1,0,0), include.drift = T, xreg = m1+m2+m3+m4+m5+m6+m7+m8+m9+m10+m11)
summary(fit100_month)
```

This gives me output but it does not give me a coefficient for each month, but only one coefficient.

Nextly, I tried

```
fit100_month = Arima(series, order=c(1,0,0), include.drift = T, xreg = m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11)
```

This gives me an error of:

> Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, xreg
>   = xreg,  :    'seasonal$order' must be a non-negative numeric vector of length 3

I'm a little lost on how to proceed and would appreciate some guidance on how to include 11 dummy variables in my arima model

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You were using quotation of text where you should use code block indentation, just FYI. Also please include a *reproducible* example.

Comment: The documentation for `forecast::Arima` is pretty clear: you need to pass in a matrix, with each regressor as a column. In the first case, you have something that looks like you want it to be a `formula`, but is just a sum of vectors. In the second, the arguments after `m1` are passed in by position, so end up in the wrong parameter. You want something like `xreg = cbind(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked at the documentation and was trying to use as.matrix() instead.    Thank you for clearing up my confusion!